# Amortized cost / insert and deletion

Tags: algorithm

```
Design a data structure to support the following two types of operations on an initially empty
set S of real numbers:
— Insert(S,x): Inserts number x into S.
— Delete(S): Deletes the largest n/2 numbers from S.

Explain how to implement this data structure with O(1) amortized cost per operation.
```

How is this possible? For me it seems like i need to sort the data structure everytime Insert is called, if its not sorted the delete would take more than O(1). So the amortized cost for Insert should be the following:

Amortized cost for insert = (S + 1)Actual cost + (S + 1)Data structure after - (S - 1)Data structure before = S + 1

With this the amortized cost is clearly not O(1)

Comment: If you're starting with an empty set, you never have to sort it even once, if you do the insertions properly (put the element in the proper place while inserting). Same goes with deleting - there's no sort at all needed even once.

Comment: I'm wondering what `n` is?

Comment: @Ken White, "put the element in the proper place while inserting" can you give some example of this? For me that sounds like sorting.

Comment: @Neil n is the elements inside S

Comment: Um, no. Write some random letters on small pieces of paper. Grab one piece of paper and put it in front of you. Grab the next one, and if it's lower than the first one put it on the left of the first, or on the right if it's higher. Repeat with a third piece, putting it in its proper location according to its value. That's not sorting, it's inserting. Sorting would be taking the entire set of papers, putting them randomly in a row all at once, and then rearranging them all to put them in the proper order.

Comment: So if we insert 3,7,1,2. then 7 compare with 3 so we got [3,7] then 1 compares with 7? So [3,1,7] then 2 compare with 1: [3,1,2,7]. Or do you mean that the first element is the pivot? What if the first one is the smallest one?

Comment: Binary insertion is still `O(log n)`. I think the answer lies in what the *output* function has to be, (presumably it has one); as such, you don't have to do strict evaluation.

Comment: @Neil i don't understand what you mean with output function. So i guess a stack and a list is not possible?

Comment: Lazy evaluation; stick them in a queue until output is requested.